# Multi-tenant database with tenant ID on every table

Tags: mysql, sql

Would there be any value in adding a FK for OrganizationID to the Group_Scopes table?  Normalization standards would say no because the relationship is transitive, but the general rule of thumb for multi-tenant with row level security seems to dictate you add the tenant id to every table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generally foreign keys help guarantee referential integrity via constraints.

Also you can perform `CASCADE` operations (you can delete or update the row from the parent table, and MySQL will automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table)

So, if you'll have a lot of tables (or tables with complex structures) using FK would be helpful because it will prevent from you making necessary checks using any other programming languages - MySQL will do it by itself

Comment: Well, in your case outside of possible additional constraints - no benefits at all.